# Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,

Tags: r

I want to plot the following as part of Wavelet Coherence Analysis in R:

```
plot(wtc.AB, plot.phase = TRUE, lty.coi=1, col.coi="grey", lwd.coi=2, lwd.sig=2, arrow.lwd=0.03, arrow.len=0.12, ylab="Scale", xlab="Years", plot.cb=TRUE, main="Wavelet Coherence: SP500 vs Uganda Sov Bond", xaxt="n")
```

However, I end up with the following error:

> Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab =
> ylab,  :    'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

I will appreciate your assistance.

I end up with the following error:

> Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab =
> ylab,  :    'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

Comment: Could you try the [following examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/biwavelet/versions/0.20.21/topics/plot.biwavelet) and check whether they work on your machine?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?